# Javascript: call a specific function on function complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, anonymous

I have a slow function that does an AJAX request:

```
function X(param1,param2){
var params={
    type: "POST",
    url: "./ajax/useful.php",
    data: "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2,
    success: function(msg){
      //do something
    }
  };
  var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
}
```

Everything works fine when I call X("asdf","qwerty").

Now, what I want to do is to be able to call function X as follows:

```
function X(param1,param2,function(){alert('hi');}){
var params={
    type: "POST",
    url: "./ajax/useful.php",
    data: "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2,
    success: function(msg){
      /////
      //I want to be able call the function in the 3rd parameter (alert in this case)
      /////
    }
  };
  var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
}
```

Now you might say why don't I just call alert('hi') directly inside the success. Sure I can do this, but I want to be able to vary what goes on inside the called function (not just a simple alert('hi'), depending on who's calling X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare your `X` function like this:

```
function X(param1,param2,callback){
```

...use the callback like this:

```
success: function(msg){
    callback();
}
```

...and call `X` like this:

```
X('a', 'b', function(){alert('hi');});
```

This works because your success handler is a *closure* over the data within your `X` function, including its arguments. It has a live reference to that information (even after `X` returns), and so later when the Ajax call completes, it can still use the `callback` argument. More on closures here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Legend, that should work. I wasn't sure of the syntax. Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0):

```
function X(param1,param2,f){
var params={
    type: "POST",
    url: "./ajax/useful.php",
    data: "param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2,
    success: function(msg){
      f();
    }
  };
  var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
}
```

should work. 
You can no call X like this:

```
X(param1,param2,function(){dowhatever})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. T.J. Crowder, above, came up with a good way of calling X whilst taking full advantage of anonymous functions.

Comment: @Eamorr my code is exactly the same the only difference is that ` callback ` is named ` f ` in my code :)